# User entering URL .Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

there are certain actions that i dont allow for certain users, however they can just put in the parameters manually and that's the issue. I have to put a lot of `If`s to check if they are allowed to do that action and that's incredibly annoying since i check if they are allowed in my view to even show them that option in the first place. Is there a way that we just have the methods get data from controllers/Views withing the application? if not how do you guys deal with this issue?
I'll put an example below

```
https://localhost:44327/Manage/Members?Username=bob1234
```

not everybody is supposed to have access to this but they can put it in manually and only way im aware of is checking for qualifications before `return view()`

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't think you can avoid using condition checks, but you might reduce them with some built-in ways.

One solution would be to check the [HttpContext's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-5.0) User, which is filled by the framework if there is authentication set up.

Another solution which also involves the HttpContext is to create an [AuthorizationPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-5.0), e.g. "AllowSelfOnly" or something which will 403 the user if it tries to access, though this comes with a sort of *hard coded* parameter logic.

On a sidenote, if you're trying to do a page where the user can manage their own settings, you'd be better to drop the parameter and use directly the currently authenticated user.